# What are the alternatives to flash messages based on php session

Tags: php, session

I have developed a very light custom framework which uses a cool and light flash message class from http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/ which uses sessions. Everything is cool, clean and works great. Problem! lol my host does not support php session :( ... What the alternatives? Cookie based, using a database?

Comment: Your host doesn't support php sessions? Do they support php at all? Because sessions are required for pretty much every php app. You could also implement some sort of php database based sessions.

Comment: If your host doesn't support PHP sessions, I highly suggest you to switch host. Either way, you can do this using a database instead, but I don't suggest you to use cookies if you are going to store data that has to be secured.

Comment: yup was surprised to find out that php sessions are not supported... it's wpengine actually which is a wordpress managed host

Comment: was thinking about security too.. i don't like cookies because of that... would have to encrypt/decrypt etc.. quite painful lol... i am starting to hate wpengine lol

Comment: i guess a database based session would work...I think codeigniter uses something like that i am not wrong...

Comment: Ask your host support. It should support sessions. If you need to work for login/ member system, how'd you manage things then.

Comment: I have no idea how wordpress manage login (probably by cookie and database sessions)... but wordpress does not really use sessions at all from what i understand (just started wordpress development)